# USPS Maximum Package Weight Not Restricting Weight

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, usps

I have a Magento CE 1.9 site. I am using USPS to ship all items under 1 lb and FedEx for all items over 1 lb. However, When I set the USPS Maximum Package Weight to 1 lb it still shows on items over 1 lb. Must I do something additional? Has anyone run in to this and have a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Magento will only enforce this if any item is >1lb. So if you have 2 * 1/2lb items it will still show a rate (it sends out 2 packages in request to USPS).

To solve this you would need to change the underlying codebase to enforce the restriction. The relevant code is in `Shipping_Model_Shipping`.

There are extensions out there to control this also.